# NSScrollView Background Texture

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

Is there any way that one can use the `NSScrollView` background texture that is used in **Safari** from within other applications?  I know how to get the `NSScrollView` to display a pattern, I just need to know if there is a named image for the texture and what the name is?  Or, if there isn't a named image, where I can find something similar?

Comment: I don't see you can't just call: scrollView.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage: myNSImageFile]; where the image file can be a reference to the images Apple use, such as scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor. See this link, admittedly for UIColor, but I reckon they may work here too... http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIColor (scroll down to the patterns section)

Comment: @Luke I had heard that on iOS there was a UIColor for the UIScrollView background pattern. I was just hoping that either there was a static method like UIColor.scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor for NSColor or someone could point me in the direction of an image that I could use.  Thanks!

Comment: Does the line I posted not exist in cocoa? Also if you're just after the image files, you'll find some small ones which you could tile on the web link I posted... else grab the description names from there & then search for them on the web, perhaps.

Comment: @Luke Yes, that setBackgroundColor exists on NSScrollView.  Thanks for the link.  I'll see what I can come up with from there.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not a cocoa developer.... but do keep us posted though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit off-topic, I think, since it's not "how to use a background texture in NSScrollView" but "where can I find a similar graphic"? But you'd only know that if you knew it wasn't a system-supplied texture. :-)

This is a custom graphic and is not available via the system. You'll need to create your own, license someone else's or find one that is free for commercial use. Search the web for "linen background" or "linen texture" etc. If you have Photoshop, there are [tutorials](http://elixirgraphics.com/index.php/entries/blog_creating_an_ios_linen_texture_in_photoshop) out there for creating your own Mac-like linen pattern.